# Rouché for positive $n$, but what for negative $n$?

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

Suppose $\Omega$ is open that contains the closed unit disc. If $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphoc with $|f(z)| < 1$ for all $z$ with $|z|=1$. How many solutions are there of $f(z)=z^n$ if $n\in \mathbb{Z}$?

For the case that $n$ is postive, it is quite easy to see because of Rouché's theorem. I am, however, stuck on the case where $n$ is negative.

Comment: None: $|f(z)| < 1 < |z|^n$ in $\Bbb D$ if $n$ is negative.

Comment: So we can also apply Rouché's theorem in the negative case? That seems simple, too simple...

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you mean. $|z|^n$ is not holomorphic in the unit disk for negative $n$, how would you apply Rouché's theorem?

Comment: @MartinR wait, how did you find that there were no solutions for $n$ negative then?

Comment: $|f(z)| < 1 < |z^n|$ implies $f(z) \ne z^n$, doesn't it?

Comment: @MartinR the first inequality only holds when $|z|=1$ ? I'm confused on how you can conclude that there are no solutions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133644/discussion-between-martin-r-and-geigercounter).